# android studio error HAXM

Tags: android, visual-studio

I changed my windows recently from 10 to 7 .. now I am getting this error when I want to open my AVD

(ntel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm is not found.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.
)

.. the HAXM is also installed... im using a 64 operating system with windows 7 .. 
the virtualizationt is enable in BIOS setting.
how can i fix it??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check whether intel virtualization technology is enabled in bios, if not enable it.
2. Make sure you have installed HAXM, you can check it in your sdk manager.

[image]

if not, install it and Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory Go to extras > intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe".

3. Restart android studio.

Comment: virtualization technology is enable or disable in BIOS ??

Comment: please see this question and help me for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812600/haxm-error-in-android-studio-3-0-with-windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver

Comment: @darkshadow  1 I had enabled the virtualization 2 Installed the Haxm  3 Restarted the studio.