# Haxm error in android studio 3.0 with windows requires a digitally signed driver

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I'll find lot's of solution in SO or in google but it's can't help full for me

**Whenever i'll start AVD then below error can show me :**

[image]

**Then i try to Uninstall the Haxm and then Re Install then show me below error :**

[image]

---

### UPDATE 14/06/2018

Now i Uninstall the HAXM and reInstall then give me a below error.

[image]

---

### UPDATE 21/06/2018

Follow below answer and it's work perfectly step No. 1 TO 10 whenever i'll follow step no. 11 then it's give me the error see below image:

[image]

Can you please any help for installing Haxm or Start the AVD.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm this might help you.

Comment: Download the digitally signed driver for haxm or disable the for digital signature in windows.

Comment: i'll try this but i'ts can't helpful for me @Ali786

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is actually indirectly related to a missing security update for Windows 7 64 bit. It is discussed in depth here.
https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/56

Here is the relevant comment from the forum

> > For the HAXM 7.2.0 release, we changed the certificate that we use to sign the Windows 7/8/8.1 driver (IntelHaxm.sys). Previously (for HAXM 7.1.0 and earlier), we used a SHA-1 certificate for these Windows versions. However, we were advised that SHA-1 algorithm is now considered insecure, and that we should replace it with SHA-256 (a variant of SHA-2). So we did that, and tested the new driver against our own Windows 7/8/8.1 systems without noticing any issue. However, apparently the new driver signature is not recognized by some Windows systems. According to this article, Windows 7 actually requires a patch to enable SHA-256 support, whereas Windows 8 and later supports it by default.

So, simply put, Intel changed the digital signature for the driver to SHA-256 from HAXM 7.2. And since this is unsupported on Win 7 64-bit without the particular Windows update, the HAXM 7.2 patch is simply not recognized as being digitally signed on these systems.

To summarize, the solution is quite simple but two-fold.

1. If you can,    then please go ahead and first try to install this
   update.
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148
2. If it works, then simply install HAXM 7.2

If you are unable to do this somehow, then you need to uninstall the 7.2 and instead download and install HAXM 7.1 from the download link.

Download link for both versions (for manual installation):
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases

**How to manually install HAXM?**

1. Unzip the file and then run intelhaxm-android.exe (or the silent
   install one, if you so prefer)
2. Run Android Studio and try the emulator again.
3. Voila!

This particular issue wasted a lot of my time on a couple of my older systems so I hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

### MY SOLUTION

**STEP 1:** Uninstall all driver of HAXM In **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features ->** *intel hardware accelerated execution manager*

**STEP 2:** In Android Studio Go in **File>Setting>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK** in the Dialog Select **SDK Tools** & **Follow STEP 3.**

**STEP 3:** In Dialog Unchecked  **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (Haxm installer)**

**STEP 4:** Open [THIS LINK](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases) and **download haxm-windows_v7_0_0.zip**

**STEP 5:** Now extract this `.zip` and copy data and paste into this path **AndroidSDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager**

**STEP 6:** Now Install `intelhaxm-android.exe` **(It's Install Successfully :)**.

**STEP 7:** Now close your android studio properly & **Restart Your Machine**

### cheers :)

---

- **See Step No 3 Image** In this image i can't select **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (Haxm installer)**

[image]

---

Comment: Wait... are you using macOS or Windows? You seem to be installing the wrong zip file for your OS.

Comment: i use window 7 64Bit

Comment: how ? my emulator work perfectly when upper steps i follow @Edric

Comment: You can use the haxm-windows_v7_0_0.zip file for windows. Updated the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

**1** : Uninstall HAXM in Control Panel
**2** : Uncheck Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (Haxm installer) in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools then Click OK
**3** : Download haxm v7_5_6.zip in [this link](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.6) and extract it
**4** : Before Install it, restart your PC and go to Advanced Boot Options by pressing **F8**
**5** : Select **Disable Driver Signature Enforcement**
**6** : Install intelhaxm-android.exe from extracted zip, wait until installation completed and should be no error with all of this step.

Hope this help