# Android Studio Emulator error "Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I was able to use Emulator in the android studio without any problems. Since today I am getting the error as: 
"Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

Virtualization is enabled in BIOS, Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager is installed in control panel - programs.
Also tried installing intelhaxm-android.exe from android sdk folder.

Please help with the error.

(i7/16gb/windows 10).

Answer (score 10):

I **solved** that problem following steps

- [disabling Hyper-v](https://youtu.be/XJTeQdJUMDM)
- reinstalling HAXM
              - Android studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

Comment: This is a bad idea. Because people who have activated Hyper-v has a reason for it. Like to use Docker. So this is not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

### Use Hyper-V instead of HAXM

I had the same error. Disabling Hyper-V avoided this error however it also stopped Docker from working properly.

To **use both the Android Emulator and Docker on Windows 10** you need to:

- Uninstall the Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
- Enable *Hyper-V* (check by running "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online" in PowerShell running as Administrator)
- Enable *Windows Hypervisor Platform*
- Restart your computer
- Enable Virtualization Technology in your computer's BIOS
- Enable Hardware Enforced Data Execution Prevention in the BIOS

Enable *Hyper-V* and *Windows Hypervisor Platform* in Control *Panel\Programs\Programs and Features* -> *Turn Windows features on or off*

[Enable Windows Hypervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xda3b.jpg)

Microsoft recommends that you use Hyper-V instead of HAXM to accelerate the Android emulator ([detailed instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows)).

Comment: To remove HAXM run C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe.

Comment: this is absolutely the right answer. But it's also important that you uncheck HAXM in Android Studios under: Tools --> SDK Manager --> SDK Tools (tab) --> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)

Comment: "intelhaxm-android.exe" can be used to remove HAXM, however unchecking "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" will also remove the installation files.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and **solved** it by **disabling the Hyper-V hypervisor** on Windows (from the "Activate/Deactivate Windows Functionalities" menu).

Answer (score 1):

1st you uninstall the hexm everywhere also in android studio :

Download haxm version haxm-macosx_v7_0_0.zip from here [Click Me](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases)

And Follow this steps : [Haxm error in android studio 3.0 with windows requires a digitally signed driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812600/haxm-error-in-android-studio-3-0-with-windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver)

Comment: getting this error on trying to install haxm - this computer does not support intel virtualization or used by hyper v. I have checked windows features and hyper-v is disabled already.

Comment: can you enable the virtualization in BIOS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable hyper-v or you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows)

You can't run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another VM, such as a VM hosted by VirtualBox, VMWare, or Docker. You must run the Android emulator directly on your system hardware

Comment: Try to improve the answer format. It will help to sounds better to reach your answer. Give link using []()

Answer (score 0):

For me Hyper-V hypervisor was not installed but still I got the error. What I did was I went to `SDK Manager->SDK Tools` and there I unchecked `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator` clicked apply. Closed my Android studio and then reopened Android studio and again went to `SDK Manager->SDK Tools` and installed `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator` by checking the item and clicking apply. And it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I need Hyper-V for Docker.

So according to the official documentation, you have 3 choices (the second solution helped me):

- You have an Intel processor and do not need to run Hyper-V at the same time as the Android Emulator.
  Use Intel HAXM.
- You have an Intel processor and do need to run Hyper-V at the same time as the Android Emulator.
  Use WHPX.
- You have an AMD processor.
  Use WHPX.

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#choose-windows-hypervisor