# Why my Emulator is not running on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, exit-code

When i try to run my app on emulator it ends with following mistakes:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812600/haxm-error-in-android-studio-3-0-with-windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Android SDK manager, on top side you can see the "Android SDK Location" go to that location and follow this path

> \extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

here you will get "**intelhaxm-android.exe**" install this setup.

Comment: Than you helped.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

In setting, inside SDK Tools, try to install "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)", this should fix your problem.