# Intel haxm installation failed?

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I tried to install HAXM for android studio and i enabled virtualization but this error happened

```
Windows requires digitally signed driver
A recently installed program tried to install an unsigned driver.
This version of Windows requires all drivers to have a valid digital signature . 
The driver is unavailable and the program that uses this driver might not work correctly.
```

any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haxm error in android studio 3.0 with windows requires a digitally signed driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812600/haxm-error-in-android-studio-3-0-with-windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver)

Comment: Are you trying on windows 7 or 10? You need to be all security updates installed before installing haxm.

Comment: my device works on windows 7 @HarshDattani

Comment: No it didn't @AliSadeghi

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this may sound bizarre, but you need to disable Windows Virtual Machine Platform from "Turn Windows features on or off" for Windows 10/11

That should work (it worked for me)!

Also, to help, you should install the Intel Processor Identification Utility, from the link below. This will help quickly monitor the status of the error. If there is an "x" next to the Intel Virtualization Technology, that means that the error still exists. But if there is a checkmark, then your problem is solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).